# detection of communication failure when "put" in queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I am using the `multiprocessing` python module with `Queue` for communication between processes.  Some processes only send (i.e. `queue.put`) and I can't seem to find a way to detect when the receiving end gets terminated abruptly.

Is there a way to detect if the process at the other end of the Queue gets terminated **without** having to `get` from the Queue?  Isn't there a signal I could trap somehow? Or do I have to periodically `get` from the Queue and trap the `EOFError` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `multiprocessing` sets up a "watch-dog" process for you to take care of crashes or kills of some of your processes.  It may be worth your while to set one up (pretty hard to do cross-platform, but if, say, you're only worried about Linux, it's not that terrible).